# NEST: Elastic Search improve query

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Using Elastic "number": "6.3.1" "lucene_version": "7.3.1" NEST: 6.1.0

I'm trying to improve the return results where i'm getting too many records that are not relevant and seeming in a bad order.

```
 protected override CreateIndexDescriptor DefineIndex(string indexName)
    {
        return new CreateIndexDescriptor(indexName)
            .Settings(s => s
                .Analysis(a => a
                    .Analyzers(aa => aa
                        .Custom("my_analyzer", pa => pa
                            .Tokenizer("my_tokenizer")
                            .Filters("standard", "lowercase")
                        )
                    )
                    .Tokenizers(ta => ta
                        .EdgeNGram("my_tokenizer", t => t
                             .MinGram(2)
                             .MaxGram(17)
                             .TokenChars(TokenChar.Letter, TokenChar.Whitespace, TokenChar.Digit)
                            )
                    )
                )
            )
            .Mappings(ms => ms
                .Map<MySearch>(m => m
                    .Properties(p => p
                        .Text(s => s
                            .Name("Field1")
                            .Analyzer("my_analyzer")
                            .SearchAnalyzer("my_analyzer")
                            .Fields(fs => fs
                                .Keyword(ss => ss
                                    .Name("raw")
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                ));
    }
```

the lookup search is

```
public void Lookup(string searchValue, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
    {
        var result = _client.Search<MyModel>(x => x
            .From((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
            .Size(pageSize)
            .Index("myindex")
            .Query(qq => qq
                .MultiMatch(mm => mm
                    .Query(searchValue.ToLowerInvariant().Trim())          
                    .Fields(f => f
                        .Field(ff => ff.Field1, 5.0)
                        .Field(ff => ff.Field2)
                        .Field(ff => ff.Field3)
                    )
                )
            )
        );
    }
```

Now I want Field1 to have more relevance, so i boost it by 5x.

I am searching with the text "alpha (beta delta)"

My currently problem is that 'alpha' is the main keyword i'm looking for. And as you can see i need to search multiple fields.  I need all matches to 'alpha' to show up first.   'beta' is really only good search match if it's with the 'delta'. But right now with what i have, it returns ALOT of matches that happen to match 'beta' cause it's a more generic term in my data set.

How can i make 'alpha', or i suppose the first word in the search to be the most important value in the search?  Should i be using Term queries?

Example... right now... if i search 'alpha'... i get back results where field1 in the document is 'prealpitate'.  Not sure why because EdgeNGram should be starting at the 'edge' not in the middle.

Comment: ok so you first want alpha field, then beta AND delta? So create a filter with alpha and a second filter with beta AND delta and alpha missing. Sort the result using _missing (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html).

Comment: Filters seem to only work on term queries, so you are saying change this to term query?

Comment: Ok, i understand better so:
1) Must: filter document with Alpha OR (Beta AND Delta) 
2) Should: Multimatch Alpha And (Beta AND Delta), boost 15
3) Should: Multimatch Alpha Not (Beta Or Delta), boost 10
The part 1 will select all document you need, the second will boost the document matching Alpha and beta and Delata, the 3rd Only alpha. Your results should be sorted. You need help for the Nest code?

Comment: yes, can you please assist .. not sure how to lay that out.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i cant test right now but should be something like that (cant test on this labtop)

The first must will return all document with alpha OR (beta And Delta)
The should will boost doc with alpha AND beta AND delta (operator and)
The last should will boost doc with alpha only
Of course you could add boost with alpha AND (beta OR delta) between

Hope it s help

```
split your searchValue in a searchValue[]
.Bool(bo => bo.
.Must(Bool(bo => bo
              .Should(
                  sh => sh.Term(te => te.Field1, searchValue[0]),
                  sh => sh.Bool(
                      boo => boo
                         .Should(
                            sho => sho.Term(te => te.Field2, searchValue[1]),
                            sho => sho.Term(te => te.Field3, searchValue[2])
                          )
                       )
                   )
                )
            )
.Should(MultiMatch(mm => mm
                    .Query(searchValue.ToLowerInvariant().Trim())          
                    .Fields(f => f
                        .Field(ff => ff.Field1)
                        .Field(ff => ff.Field2)
                        .Field(ff => ff.Field3)
                    )
                    .Operator(Operator.And)
                    .Boost(15)
                )
)
.Should(Bool(bo => bo
                        .Must(ff => ff.Term(te => te.Field1, searchValue[0]))
                        .MustNot(ff => ff
                            .Bool(
                                boo => boo
                                    .Should(
                                        sh => sh.Term(te => te.Field2, searchValue[1]),
                                        sh => sh.Term(te => te.Field3, searchValue[2])
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        .Boost(10)
                        )
                )
)
```

Comment: does this need different analyzers?